# how to retrieve all data from firebase onto the page using listview?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

it is showing null while retrieving the data from firebase using listview? I want to fetch all the values onto the page]

```
public class viewpgdetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private TextView ft_email, ft_address, ft_fact, ft_owner, ft_phone, ft_pin, ft_rent, ft_pgname;
    private FirebaseStorage fstorage;
    private ListView list_view;
    private StorageReference storageRef;
    private ImageView view_img1, view_img2, view_img3, view_img4, view_img5;


    //FirebaseListAdapter adapter;
    public static Context context;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    user info;


   // final String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewpgdetails);
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

       // String key=mDatabase.getKey();
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = database.getReference().child("USER");
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);


        list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                        user info =ds.getValue(user.class);
                        //adapter.add(String.valueOf(info.getOwner()+"   "));
                     // adapter.add(String.valueOf(info.getEmail()));
                    adapter.add(String.valueOf(info.getAddress()));

                                //+ info.getOwner().toString() + "    " + info.getPhone().toString() + "   " + info.getAddress().toString() + "    " + info.getPin().toString() + "  " + info.getFact().toString() + "   " + info.getRent().toString());

                    }

                list_view.setAdapter(adapter);

                // showData(dataSnapshot);

                //Toast.makeText(viewpgdetails.this, dataSnapshot.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(viewpgdetails.this, "failed to get data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "showing null"? Is there any error message you've forgot to share?

Comment: Please provide your db structure

Comment: What do you mean through "it is showing null while retrieving the data from firebase using listview"? Please also add your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

[I have added my database structure below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfvLG.png)[From Firebase docs:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

> The child_added event is typically used when retrieving a list of items from the database.

So I think you should write something like:

```
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
      user info = dataSnaphot.getValue(user.class);
      adapter.add(String.valueOf(info.getAddress()));
}
```

Where `ref` should be reference to database parent of all users, something like:
[image]